# f:ajax tag is not found in JSF2.0 lib

Tags: jsf-2

HI,

Want to implement a solution with JSF2.0 ajax functionality. As of now am not using any of its implementations like richfaces or icefaces.

I am using the jsf-impl-2.0.2 and jsf-api-2.0.2.jar and using apache-tomcat-6.0.16.

Still getting unknown tag error in f:ajax.

Some of my queries,

Can't I implement ajax by just using these JSF libraies or do I have to use mandatorily any of its implementation like richfaces or icefaces.

If i have some ajax utility that JSF 2.0 itself gives then what is the purpose of using richfaces and icefaces as my page is a v

Answer (score 2):

the reason for your problem is that you are using jsp page (and inside that jsp you are writing the   `<f:ajax>`.
This is not supported by the jsp pages in jsf 2.0.
To use `<f:ajax>`  you need to have xhtml pages.

Answer (score 0):

JSF 2.0 has built-in ajax support. You don't need any additional libraries.

If your libs are ok, you should post your error message and some of your source code with ajax calls. Then we can help you (maybe).

Richfaces and Icefaces are component libraries on top of JSF. Both have online showcases to see which components the provide. I would add Primefaces to this list:

[Icefaces showcase](http://component-showcase.icefaces.org/component-showcase/showcase.iface)

[Richfaces showcase](http://exadel.com/web/portal/richfacesdemo)

[Primefaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/)

Comment: Okay thanks, but am not seeing the f:ajax in JSF impl lib. This is the version of the tld - <taglib xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.1">                                                      But there is no tag for ajax. Can u tell me the correct lib to use the ajaxified version of JSF (2)

Comment: If you use jsp as view component, try these taglib definitions: `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f" %>`

Comment: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /JSP/DataTableDemo.jsp(16,3) No tag "ajax" defined in tag library imported with prefix "f"
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:40)
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:407)
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:198)
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseCustomTag(Parser.java:1220)
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1456)

Comment: org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseBody(Parser.java:1664)
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseOptionalBody(Parser.java:1011)
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseCustomTag(Parser.java:1279)
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1456)
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseBody(Parser.java:1664)
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseOptionalBody(Parser.java:1011)
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseCustomTag(Parser.java:1279)
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1456)

Comment: org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:133)
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:216)
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:103)
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:153)
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:314)
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:294)
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:281)
 org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:566)

Comment: com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:106)
 com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
 com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
 javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:313)